# Android (ICS): WebView fails to appear when using loadData with HTML/JS that modifies window.location

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm experiencing trouble with WebView's `loadData` method when passing in a certain HTML payload. The payload contains some JavaScript that sets `window.location` to a URL with a custom scheme (`mycustomscheme://` in the example below). The reason for this is that I'd like my application code to be able to catch various JS events in its implementation of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`.

On my Galaxy Nexus device (running Ice Cream Sandwich), `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` works as intended, but the WebView doesn't ever appear on-screen. If I remove the `window.location` code from the JS, the WebView shows up just fine. The code also seems to work correctly on all pre-ICS devices I've tried.

Am I missing something obvious in the code below?

**Edit:** I could use `addJavascriptInterface` to accomplish the same thing, but I'd prefer not to do that, since not all of the HTML is generated by me. To preserve the clarity of the code sample, I've omitted this detail.

```java
public class ICSWebViewTestActivity extends Activity {
    private RelativeLayout mLayout;
    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        mLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        setContentView(mLayout);

        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());

        String data = 
            "<html><head>" +
            "<script>" +
            "window.onload = f;" + // works if this line is removed
            "function f() { window.location = 'mycustomscheme://finish'; }" + 
            "</script>" +
            "</head>" +
            "<body><h1 style='color:blue'>Hello, world!</h1></body>";

        mWebView.loadData(data, "text/html", "utf-8");

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

        mLayout.addView(mWebView, rlp);
    }

    private void doAction() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Doing action!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("mycustomscheme://")) {
                doAction();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am also encountering this, did you ever find a suitable workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting `window.location`, why not call [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29) to the WebView and then call the interfaceName from javascript?

Comment: I'm wary of using `addJavascriptInterface` since part of the HTML is provided by someone else. I'd prefer not to expose an entire object to the outside world. I omitted this detail originally since I thought it would add clutter to the original question, but I'll edit it now.